# How to exclude text anchored by specific tags from lxml text_content()

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I know there were similar questions to this, but since they didn't solve the problem, please bear with me why I go through the issue one more time.

Here's my string:

```
normal = """
  <p>
    <b>
      <a href='link1'>        Forget me  </a>
    </b>     I need this one      <br>
    <b>
     <a href='link2'>  Forget me too  </a>
    </b> Forget me not <i>even when</i> you go to sleep <br>
    <b>  <a href='link3'>  Forget me three  </a>
    </b>  Foremost on your mind <br>
   </p>    
"""
```

I start with:

```
target = lxml.html.fromstring(normal)
tree_struct = etree.ElementTree(target)
```

Now, I basically need to ignore everything anchored by the `<a>` tag. But if I run this code:

```
for e in target.iter():
   item = target.xpath(tree_struct.getpath(e))
   if len(item)>0:
       print(item[0].text)
```

I get nothing; if, on the other hand, I change the `print` instruction to:

```
  print(item[0].text_content())
```

I get this output:

```
Forget me
 I need this one

 Forget me too

Forget me not
even when
you go to sleep


 Forget me three

Foremost on your mind
```

While my desired output is:

```
 I need this one

Forget me not
even when
you go to sleep    

Foremost on your mind
```

Aside for giving the wrong output, it's also inelegant. So I must be missing something obvious, though I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making this unnecessarily complicated. There is no need to create the `tree_struct` object and use `getpath()`. Here is a suggestion:

```python
from lxml import html

normal = """
  <p>
    <b>
      <a href='link1'>        Forget me  </a>
    </b>     I need this one      <br>
    <b>
     <a href='link2'>  Forget me too  </a>
    </b> Forget me not <i>even when</i> you go to sleep <br>
    <b>  <a href='link3'>  Forget me three  </a>
    </b>  Foremost on your mind <br>
   </p>
"""

target = html.fromstring(normal)

for e in target.iter():
    if not e.tag == "a":
        # Print text content if not only whitespace 
        if e.text and e.text.strip():
            print(e.text.strip())
        # Print tail content if not only whitespace
        if e.tail and e.tail.strip():
            print(e.tail.strip())
```

Output:

```
I need this one
Forget me not
even when
you go to sleep
Foremost on your mind
```

Comment: "I think you are making this unnecessarily complicated" - absolutely; at some point I got so frustrated with this, I couldn't think clearly anymore... Thanks; that's brilliantly simple!